# SQL dacpac deployment in azure devops CI/CD

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, cicd, dacpac

i have deployed sql dacpac changes in azure devops ci/cd. Everything went well. But after deployment, in the database properties -> options -> Recovery -> Page Verify is set to NONE instead of CHECKSUM. Before deployment it was CHECKSUM. I have additional arguments set as eg: /p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true. Please suggest how to handle in dacpac release pipeline. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you add a step to your pipeline where the script is just generated (`DeploymentAction: 'Script'`) and not executed so this can be reviewed with a [Manual Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines) task and sanity checked to validate what it will do first. (At least for production)

Regarding this issue you should set the desired option in the Database Project so it is reflected in the dacpac.

Go to project properties -> project settings tab -> Database Settings button -> Operational tab and it is in the "Recovery" section.

[image]

Selecting this adds the following entry to the *.sqlproj file

```
<PageVerify>CHECKSUM</PageVerify>
```